# How to make this CoreMotion code work on retina iPod touch devices?

Tags: iphone, ios, accelerometer, ipod-touch, core-motion

I have developed a small app which uses CoreMotion to get tilt information.

But it does not work on iPod touches. I tested on the first retina display iPod touch with iOS 5.1. The gyroAvailable property returns YES, so I assume this iPod does have a gyro.

This code works fine on iPhone 4:

```
CMMotionManager *mm = [[CMMotionManager alloc] init];
self.motionManager = mm;
[motionManager setDeviceMotionUpdateInterval:0.05];

CMDeviceMotionHandler motionHandler = ^(CMDeviceMotion *motion, NSError *error) {
    [self handleMotion:motion error:error];
};

[motionManager startDeviceMotionUpdatesUsingReferenceFrame:CMAttitudeReferenceFrameXArbitraryCorrectedZVertical toQueue:[NSOperationQueue currentQueue] withHandler:motionHandler];
```

`startDeviceMotionUpdatesUsingReferenceFrame` seems to be the culprit but I couldn't figure out from the documentation that this method would not work on devices which have no gyro.

All I need is a precise output of how much the user tilts the device to the left or right in portrait mode.

What alternatives do I have?

Answer (score 2):

If you wanna use iPod, use 'CMAttitudeReferenceFrameXArbitraryZVertical'.
Because iPad has no magnetometer.